# exponentiation in Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C

Tags: c, algorithm, exponentiation

**When addressed exponentiation in chapter 2, the author mentioned**

"The number of multiplications required is clearly at most 2 log n(the base is 2), because at
most two multiplications (if n is odd) are required to halve the problem. Again,a recurrence formula can be written and solved."

**The code as follow:**

```
int pow( int x, unsigned int n)
{
/*1*/ if( n == 0 )
/*2*/ return 1;
/*1*/ if( n == 1 )
/*4*/ return x;
/*5*/ if( even( n ) )
/*6*/ return( pow( x*x, n/2 ) );
else
/*7*/ return( pow( x*x, n/2 ) * x );
}
```

**Q**:
As the author said,

2^16 need at most 8 multiplications

2^15        ...   7 ...

2^14        ...   7 ...

2^13        ...   7 ...

2^12        ...   7 ...

In fact, I perfrom the code:

2^16        ....  4 ...

2^15        ....  6 ...

2^14        ...   5 ...

2^13        ...   5 ...

2^12        ...   4 ...

So, is somewhere wrong?

Comment: Divide 16 4 times by 2. It takes 4 iterations. So the book may be wrong.

Comment: he says at most so it is an upper bound estimation. All your numbers are lower so his upper bound stands. ( But may be improved)

Comment: Not sure what your complaint is. He says the number of multiplications is `<= 2 log n` (that's what 'at most' means). The number of multiplications in your case `n = 2^16` is `4`, which is indeed '<= 8', in accordance with the author's statement.

Comment: If I say 'the number of legs on an arbitrary human is **at most** 7', I'm making a true statement.

Comment: @KamiKaze So how to get the upper bound `2 log n`?

Comment: @AakashM So how to get the upper bound `2 log n`?

Comment: Analysis as it was done in the book I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no contradiction or mistake -- the book gives an upper bound, and you're looking at the exact number of multiplications.

The exact number of multiplications (for n>0) is floor(log_2(n)) + bitcount(n) - 1. That's just by inspecting the code -- the even cases (which perform one multiplication) correspond to 0 bits in the input, the odd cases (which perform an extra multiplication) correspond to 1 bits in the input, and the code stops when it reaches the highest bit.

The book says that 2*log_2(n) is an upper bound for the number of multiplications. That's consistent with the exact formula: floor(log_2(n)) <= log_2(n) and bitcount(n) - 1 <= log_2(n). So floor(log_2(n)) + bitcount(n) - 1 <= 2*log_2(n).

From the exact formula, you can see that the lower the bitcount of n, the worse the upper bound is. The very worst cases are when n is a power of 2: then exactly log_2(n) multiplications will be performed, and the upper bound is off by a factor of 2. The very best cases are when n is one less than a power of 2: then the upper bound will be off by only 1. That matches your empirical table of results.

Comment: I like this analysis since it makes it easy to see that the worst case (for number of multiplications) is when __n__ is one less than a power of 2. It took me a few moments to realize that you consider the "worst case" and "best case" _agreement_ between the predicted number of multiplications and the actual number of multiplications, while I considered "worst case" and "best case" for the number of multiplications.

Comment: Perfectly make me clear.But what's **and the upper bound is off by a factor 2** means? A little confused.

Comment: By that I meant that in the case that n is a power of 2, the upper bound is 2log_2(n), and the exact number of multiplications is log_2(n). The upper bound is 2 times the exact number -- so it's off/incorrect by a factor of 2. I note I accidentally omitted the word "of" in the answer here, so perhaps that's what was confusing -- but I fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

Finding **x^n** will take *at most* **2 log n** multiplications, since it is possible for **n/2** to be odd at every iteration. For example:

```
pow(2, 15) --> pow(2 * 2, 7) * 2
           --> pow(4 * 4, 3) * 4 * 2
           --> pow(16 * 16, 1) * 16 * 4 * 2
```

This is six multiplications (two multiplications per function call); **2 * log(15) ~= 7.8**. So the upper bound is satisfied. The best case is **n** a power of 2, which takes only **log n** multiplications.

To calculate the complexity, consider that this algorithm reduces **n** by half **k** times, until **n** is between 1 and 2; that is, we have:

> 1 ≤ <sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>2<sup>k</sup></sub> < 2

So:

> 2<sup>k</sup> ≤ n < 2<sup>k+1</sup>
>   ⇒ k ≤ log n < k+1
>   ⇒ (log n) - 1 < k ≤ log n

Thus, the algorithm takes **log n** steps, and since the worst case is two multiplications per step, at most **2 log n** multiplications are required.

Comment: As you said  **(log n) - 1 < k ≤ log n** , at most **2 log n** multiplications.And whether is the number of multiplications more than ** 2( (log n) - 1)? So the multiplications of **2^12** should less than or equal to 7 and more than 5.

Comment: @Jedore-- for **2^12**, **2.58 < k ≤ 3.58**, but **k** (the number of steps) is an integer, so **k = 3**. The number of multiplications is at most 6, since there are at most 2 multiplications per step. Following [@Paul Hankin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43001678/6879826), **bitcount(12) = 2**, so the actual number of multiplications is **⌊log 12 + 1⌋ = 4**. You can verify that this is the actual number of multiplications by following the evaluation of `pow(2, 12)`.